# Customize biblatex key for online entries

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biblatex for the scientific resources I'm citing. But I also want to add a second list for all online sources that I reference. I have split the bibliography in one file `references.bib` and one `online.bib` and I print two bibliographies with:

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, nottype=online]
\printbibliography[title={Web References}, type=online]
```

I use the `alphabetic-verb` bibliography style which uses keys/labels like [ABD+14], which are the author initials and the date of publication.

The problem is, for the online source I often don't know the authors or the publication date. In the case that I don't have authors I would like to build the key using the first letters of the title.

How can I customize the bibliography key to be build from the title in the case, that no author is specified?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber,style=alphabetic-verb]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@Article{a,
  author    = {Some Author and Some Otherauthor and More Of Thiskind and A Longlist},
  title     = {Some Paper Title},
  journal   = {Journal of Papers},
  year      = {2018},
}
@InProceedings{b,
  author    = {Some Author and Some Otherauthor},
  title     = {Some Other Paper Title},
  journal   = {Journal of Papers},
  year      = {2019},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{online.bib}
@online{texoverflow,
  title={TeX Stack Exchange},
  shorttitle={TeX},
  urldate={2020-01},
  url={https://tex.stackexchange.com/},
  note   = {\url{https://web.archive.org/web/20200101144309/https://tex.stackexchange.com/}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
\addbibresource{online.bib}

\begin{document}

Two papers \cite{a,b}.

Tex StackExchange is an online community\footnote{Stackoverflow: \cite{texoverflow}}.

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, nottype=online]
\printbibliography[title={Web References}, type=online]

\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image]

But I would like to have something like [Tex] as key for the online reference.

**Edit** I've added an entry with only two authors to also cover this case.

Answer (score 2):

This is straightforward. The label is controlled by `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate`.

The default definition is:

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  }
}
```

So you could just add `shorthand={TeX}` to your entry and this would be used as the label.

In the comments @moewe suggests (and you should listen to him) that adding `label={TeX}` to your entry is the best option. The description of this field from the `biblatex` manual explains how it works:

> A designation to be used by the citation style as a substitute for the regular label if any data required to generate the regular label is missing. For example, when an author-year citation style is generating a citation for an entry which is missing the author or the year, it may fall back to `label`. See § 2.3.2 for details. Note that, in contrast to `shorthand`, `label` is only used as a fallback. See also `shorthand`.

If you wanted to use the title, then you would need to adjust the definition of `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate` slightly. You would have to tell the definition to use the `labeltitle` field:

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
    \field{labeltitle}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  }
}
```

By default, this will use *TeX Stack Exchange* as the label, which is a bit long. But if you add a `shorttitle` field to your entry, then this will be used instead.

Unless you need to keep your bib entries flexible between styles and using the `shorthand` field would mess things up for you, then simply using `shorthand={TeX}` is probably the easiest and best option.

## MWE

This MWE demonstrates using the title as the label.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@Article{a,
  author    = {Some Author and Some Otherauthor and More Of Thiskind and A Longlist},
  title     = {Some Paper Title},
  journal   = {Journal of Papers},
  year      = {2018},
}
@online{texoverflow,
  title={TeX Stack Exchange},
  shorttitle={TeX},
  urldate={2020-01},
  url={https://tex.stackexchange.com/},
  note   = {\url{https://web.archive.org/web/20200101144309/https://tex.stackexchange.com/}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber,style=alphabetic-verb]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left,final]{labelname}
    \field{labeltitle}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  }
}

\begin{document}

A Paper \cite{a}

Tex StackExchange is an online community\footnote{Stackoverflow: \cite{texoverflow}}.

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, nottype=online]
\printbibliography[title={Web References}, type=online]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But there is a problem if one or two authors are specified for an entry. In this case the year is not added.

Comment: I think the `final` in `\field[strwidth=1,strside=left,final]{labelname}` is not needed and actually causes undesirable behaviour for the case of two names. `final` terminates the *complete* label not just the current `\labelelement`.

Comment: This seams to do the trick. But why does this not print the title in all cases?

Comment: You may also want to mention the `label` field. IMHO it is the standard way to provide a replacement label. `shorthand` always overrides the citation label (which can be unexpected for `numeric` and `authoryear` styles), but `label` is only a fallback in case stuff is missing.

Comment: @white_gecko The directives in a single `\labelelement` are executed from top to bottom. The first non-empty output becomes the `\labelement` and the next `\labelelement` is processed. If a `final` element is non-empty, the *complete* label is terminated. Since the non-`@online` examples have `author`s, the first `\labelelement` consists of the author names.

Comment: @moewe, Ah I misunderstood how the `final` option works. Using `label` does sound better. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @DavidPurton Happy new year to you and your family...

Comment: @MadyYuvi, Thank you! You too! :)